# Vertex shader not compiling after moving to ES 3.0 on IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, shader

After moving all my shaders to ES3.0 , my compileShader is faulting on the first line.

`#version 300`

It gives a syntax error:
ERROR: 0:2: '' : syntax error: #version

If it was the wrong version then I would have expected to get unsupported version, not syntax error.  So this is baffling why it won't recognize the syntax.  I checked the source being passed to the compile shader and it begins clearly with #version 300\n\n\n.

And after setting the context my version is "OpenGL ES 3.0 Apple A7 GPU - 95.16".

This is how I compile it:

```
GLint status;
const GLchar *source;

source = (GLchar *) [ [ NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ] UTF8String ];

if (!source)
{
    DebugLog(@"Failed to load shader %@", file);
    return FALSE;
}

*shader = glCreateShader( type );
glShaderSource( *shader, 1, &source, NULL );
glCompileShader( *shader );
```

Comment: Please show the full shader and how you load/compile it.

Comment: I just managed to get beyond the error.  If I use #version core , it is able to handle the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for OpenGL ES 3.0 is `#version 300 es`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this error by appending core to the #version command.  It seems to be an optional parameter but it helped me get beyond the syntax error.

`#version core`